# Best way to release a Nuitka-compiled software?

Tags: mit, gpl-2, python

My question would be: If I wrote software in Python and compiled it with [Nuitka](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka) and would like to publish it under either the GPL v2 or MIT license for others, should I also attach the original .py source?

Or in terms of "transparency" is the source generated by Nuitka already enough? I'd be a little jealous of the code I've written, but I'd also like to be transparent.

Answer (score 3):

The [GPL v2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html) defines "source code" as meaning (Section 3):

> The source code for a work means the preferred form of the work for making modifications to it.

In your case, that is clearly the Python source; nobody wants to work on the generated C source code.

The MIT license does not define anything similar. However, I would say the *spirit* of open source would be to distribute the Python code.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications. And how should I publish it? For example, Nuitka creates 3 folders together with the binary: myapp.build myapp.dist and myapp.onefile-build. So I should publish these 3 directories (or just some of these?) and maybe create another "source" directory with python source? It could go well? I know that everyone does as they see fit, I just want some advice, thanks

Comment: I know essentially nothing about Nuitka. The GPL requirements are to provide the preferred form for making modifications, and any build scripts etc necessary to create the binaries. You don't need to provide intermediate forms if they can be generated.

Comment: @gewdfa: Think of it in this way: suppose you have a brand new computer and you want to use it to make changes to your project. Which files & scripts (that are specific to your project) would you want to copy onto it to create the new version? That is what you should be publishing as the source code under the GPL license.

Comment: @gewdfa If those directories are generated by the Nuitka tool, then you would not normally distribute them. You could write in the developer notes (addressed to people who are intending to modify or compile your project) that you're using Nuitka and point to where to find it or mention how to install it using standard Python package managers (e.g. package name and version you used).